# How to authorize the security identifier (SID) in Windows service that handles eSIM-related operation requests

Tags: c++, c++-winrt, sid

I wanted to get the  security identifier (SID) to authorized by the Windows service that handles eSIM-related operation requests.

Comment: Can we able to do it manually **authorize the SID for esim** in windows, or is it only possible by operators

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.